# How can i configure my Geany Text Editor like this below picture?

Tags: fonts, themes, geany, geany-plugin

[Geany with Cool Font & Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpBlP.png)

In this picture above, i want to know which font & which theme is this ?

I also want to configure my Geany Text Editor like above picture.
I tried myfont.com, whatfontis.com & fontsquirrel also but unable to find the name of this font.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian/Ubuntu font is set in `~/.config/geany/geany.conf` Look the settings matching pattern: `*_font`.

According to the [documentation](https://www.geany.org/manual/dev/index.html#fonts), font settings is also available in UI: *Preferences > Interface Preferences > Fonts*